# Como Mostrar los detalles de un registro en una vista , que sean diferentes de NULL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc

Estoy trabajando en una vista con razor en MVC5 , y no logro hacer que no me aparezcan los detalles que dejo nulos al registrar.

Ejemplo en la imagen tengo varias preguntas pero otras se dejaron vacías por que no eran necesarias como puedo hacer para que no me aparezcan esos campos vacíos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

controlador.
`public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Formularios formularios = await db.Formularios.FindAsync(id);
            if (formularios == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(formularios);
        }`
En la vista tengo una tabla que me muestra las preguntas:

```
        <table class="table table-hover table-responsive" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Numero
                </th>
                <th>
                    Descripcion de Pregunta.
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Pregunta 1
                </td>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.P1)
                </th>
            </tr>
```

Comment: deberias agregar codigo tanto de tu clase como de tu controlador y vista para  que asi  tu duda pueda resolverse con mas facilidad

Comment: Recuerda siempre agregar un [mcve] para poderte ayudar.

Comment: Esta bien!! lo voy hacer disculpen!

Comment: a ver primero que nada esta respuestas vienen de una tabla o base de datos cierto, entonces el problema no es el html , vista o el controlador esta en la consulta.  y si usas SQL y para eso seria una consulta tipo: Select * from TableName where ColumnName is not NULL

Comment: A nivel de base de datos seria asi como dices pero en MVC5 no se trabaja con querys asi, estoy usando un modelo del cual traigo los datos ya creados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ayudarte de linq en tu consulta:

```
Formularios formularios = await db.Formularios.FindAsync(id).Where(x => x.P1 != null);
```

La clave está en el where...

Comment: Gracias Hermano!